# I can't apply the modification of my data selected from a table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem in my code when I try to modify a row from a table, I work with AngularJS as client and ASP.Net as the rest API, this is my HTML code :

```
<table ng-controller="etudmodifCtrl">
<thead>
</thead>
 <tbody >
 <tr ng-repeat="store in currentPageStores>
       <td align="center">{{store.LastName}}</td>
       <td align="center">{{store.FirstName}}</td>
       <td align="center">{{store.Email}}</td> 
       <td align="center" >{{store.Id}}</td>
       <td align="center" ng-controller="etuddeleteCtrl">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">....</div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <label>LastName</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="nomet">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>FirstName</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="prenomet">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                //click on this button will apply the modification
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button id="button" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
     //this button opens the modal in which I will modify the data
         <button ng-click="open(store.Id)" data-target="#myModal">Modify</button>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

and this is the controller:

```
.controller("etudmodifCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "logger","$route", function ($scope, $http, logger,$route) {


                          $scope.errors = [];
                          $scope.msgs = [];

                           $scope.open = function (Id) {

                               console.log("ID open---");
                               console.log(Id);
                          $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/'+Id})

                                  .success(function (data) {
                                     $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
                                     $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
                                     $scope.prenomet=data.FirstName;
                                     $scope.nomet=data.LastName;
                                     $scope.email=data.Email;
                                      console.log("success display");

                         document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
                           console.log("ID après modifetud---");
                           console.log(Id);
                           $http({method: 'PUT',
                                url:'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/modifier/'+Id,
                                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                                data:'{"FirstName":"'+$scope.prenomet+'","LastName":"'+$scope.nomet+'","Email":"'+$scope.email+'"}'
                            }

                                   )

                                  .success(function () {
                                      console.log("-----success-----"+Id);
                                      console.log($scope.prenomet+" "+$scope.nomet+" "+$scope.email);
                                      logger.logSuccess("etudiant a été modifié avec succès");

                                  }).error(function () {

                              logger.logError("echec de modification de l'étudiant");
                              console.log("data error ...");
                          });
                                 }

                                  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                              console.log("data error ...");
                          });

                           }}])
```

Per example If I select the row of table with Id=6 I get correctly the data in the input forms,but when I try to modify the input data then clic on the "OK" button I get always the old data not the modifed one

with 
Id=6,and $scope.prenomet=Student6,$scope.nomet=6,$scope.email=student6@yahoo.com(without modifcation),if I modify this data to scope.prenomet=Student66,$scope.nomet=66,$scope.email=student66@yahoo.com 
I get this on console:

```
ID open---
6
success display
ID après modifetud---
6
-----success-----6
Student6 6 student6@yahoo.com
success
```

have you any idea please about the problem,thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things that should be updated just to get this working.

In your HTML:

```
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">....</div>
        <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label>LastName</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="formData.nomet">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label>FirstName</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="formData.prenomet">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="formData.email">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        //click on this button will apply the modification
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <!-- May need $parent.editRow() in ng-click if $scope is an issue -->
           <button id="button" type="button" data-ng-click="editRow()" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In your controller:

Remove the function `document.getElementById()` from your success context and put it outside the scope of it. You can access the submit function via `ng-click` Also, rewrite it to be a `$scope` function. Mixing jQuery in with Angular is just causing you to work too hard to get what you need to do done. Also, since you are using a modal, it is advisable to use the . notation in the $scope objects. It is cleaner and you will not run into errors due to the modal's child scope.

```
$scope.open = function (Id) {    
  console.log("ID open---");
  console.log(Id);
  // This GET should be in an Angular service injected into your controller and called from here.
  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/'+Id})
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
      $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
      $scope.formData = {}; // Base object for your form.
      $scope.formData.prenomet = data.FirstName;
      $scope.formData.nomet = data.LastName;
      $scope.formData.email = data.Email;
      console.log("success display");
    })
}

$scope.editRow = function() {
  console.log("ID après modifetud---");
  console.log(Id);
  // This PUT should be in an Angular service injected into your controller and called from here.
  $http({method: 'PUT',
    url:'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/modifier/'+Id,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data:'{"FirstName": "'+$scope.formData.prenomet+'", "LastName":"'+$scope.formData.nomet+'", "Email":"'+$scope.formData.email+'"}'
  })
  .success(function () {
    console.log("-----success-----"+Id);
    console.log($scope.formData.prenomet+" "+$scope.formData.nomet+" "+$scope.formData.email);
    logger.logSuccess("etudiant a été modifié avec succès");

  }).error(function () {
    logger.logError("echec de modification de l'étudiant");
    console.log("data error ...");
}
```

I have not tested this code but it should be very close to what you will need to make this work.

Comment: thanks @buzzsaw for your code,but I have an error of undifined Id at this line: url:'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/modifier/'+Id,

Comment: @hanali In your $scope.open() function, add the line $scope.rowId = Id and then in your editRow() function url string replace +Id with + $scope.rowId. That should resolve your undefined error.